# Ubuntu 20.04 getting freeze whenever i start running any application

Tags: nvidia, freeze

Until i start any application it's running fine. I can open terminal and it's connected to wifi properly but Whenever i start any application my ubuntu 20.04 getting freeze. It was fine until i restart last day. I didn't do anything special before restart.

PC details -

- ASUS Vivobook pro
- Inter core i7, 7th generation
- 16GB RAM
- NVIDIA Geforce GTX Graphics

Comment: Terminal is also an application. Which application(s) were you trying to run?

Comment: i tried chrome,mozila,phpstorm etc..

Comment: Do you have SSH installed and can you use it?

Comment: Yes i can puspam.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: may i know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by booting recovery mode. But every time while i boot in regular process it's happened. So i installed ubuntu again.

Comment: Please give the details on how you solved your problem. It will help others.